# facebook C# SDK - They are so many, which should I use

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I initially saw this:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

but than  found out https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

now, which should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the [one on Codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). The one on github hasn't had any commits since July 2010. The codeplex one is also the recommended SDK by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx).

There is also http://facesharp.codeplex.com/ which seems to take a different approach. Se discussion here http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/247618.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the offical micrsoft one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx as it come with good examples and is fairly easy to use. I am guessing you are using Visaul studio to develop? it comes with some tooling as well

found loads of good information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cc895481

Comment: Where did you learn to use the SDK. The samples are very very basic, and there is no documentation. Which is the best way to learn how to use the sdk?